# Получить несколько таблиц в массив из Mysql (php)

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно получить несколько таблиц в один массив, как это правильно реализовать? Я для теста себе такой вариант набросал, но нужно переделать нормально.

```
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `itemprice`");
        $allprod = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $allprod = json_encode($allprod); 
        $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `status`");
        $allprod2 = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $allprod2 = json_encode($allprod2); 
        $allprod = "[" . $allprod . ',' . $allprod2 . "]";
        print_r($allprod);
```

Получить массив массивов таблиц. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если массив надо плоский, то сначала merge, потом encode:

```
$allprod = json_encode(array_merge($allprod,$allprod2))
```

Если не плоский:

```
$allprod = json_encode([$allprod,$allprod2])
```

Comment: вообще переменные лучше назвать осмысленней и не переприсваивать кучу раз

Comment: Спасибо! То есть каждую таблицу все равно нужно отдельным запросом доставать? Это не настоящие названия переменных.

Comment: ну, если их 2 -- не страшно; было бы 20 ...

Comment: Вообще надо понять, если тормозит, то что: количество запросов или содержимое. Если количество -- можно делать `UNION`. Если содержимое -- написать вместо `*` толко нужные поля. Тут скорее всего оптимизировать и не надо.

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можно оптимизировать кодб выполняя запросы в цикле:

```
<?php
$tables = ['itemprice', 'status'];
$allprod = [];

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $query   = "SELECT * FROM `$table`";
    $result  = $mysqli->query($query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $allprod[$table] = json_encode($data); 
}

var_dump($allprod);
```

Здесь можно увидеть пример исполнения кода: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=55fe635e85c2e41c7a2d8ed1ebbb353e&sqlses=6baf645fd615b4d3c33aa45c4c5d715d)

Если табицы имеют одинаковую структуру полей, можно использовать один запрос к базе с помощью `UNION`:

```
<?php
$tables = ['itemprice', 'other_itemprice'];
$allprod = [];
$query = "";

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $query   .= ($query ? " UNION ":"") . "SELECT * FROM `$table`";
}

echo "$query\n\n";

$result  = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$allprod = json_encode($data); 

print_r($allprod);
```

[Прмер кода](https://phpize.online/?phpses=1147bdb5c0f7d192bda6c2f3df19c4b6&sqlses=3cdd743e126f1543a64af768fa44a11b)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло, только json_encode в моем случае лучше применить к результату, после того как цикл сформирует массив.